# fetching from mysql between multiple time range

Tags: php, mysql

i can only select between two dates in mysql.

```
<?php
//db connection goes here
$query=mysql_query("select count(*)as total from table where DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '06:00:00' and '07:00:00'")
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if($data) {
echo ' '.$data['total'];
}
?>
```

i want to fetch between multiple-time `6:00:00-7:00:00 07:30:00-08:30:00 09:00:00-10:00:00` in `H:i:s` and fetch a report like

```
               usercount    
06:00 - 07:00   count no of user
07:30 - 08:30   count no of user
09:00 - 10:00   count no of user
```

can i do it in a single query?

Comment: where it is overlapped?i am not getting your point

Comment: 6:00-7:00 7:30-8:30 here it's overlapped

Comment: FWIW, I cannot see an overlap.

Comment: Yes. That was not overlap. I overlooked it. It is a *gap*. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a case statement, and using the HAVING to ignore other time range (cheating really - just want to avoid rechecking the time ranges in a WHERE clause):-

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:00:00' and '07:00:00'
                THEN '6:00:00-7:00:00'
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:30:00' and '08:30:00'
                THEN '07:30:00-08:30:00'
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '09:00:00' and '10:00:00'
                THEN '09:00:00-10:00:00'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS TimeRange,
        COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY TimeRange
HAVING TimeRange IS NOT NULL
```

EDIT - putting it out from PHP as requested:-

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT CASE
                    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:00:00' and '07:00:00'
                        THEN '6:00:00-7:00:00'
                    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:30:00' and '08:30:00'
                        THEN '07:30:00-08:30:00'
                    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '09:00:00' and '10:00:00'
                        THEN '09:00:00-10:00:00'
                    ELSE NULL
                END AS TimeRange,
                COUNT(*) AS total
        FROM table
        GROUP BY TimeRange
        HAVING TimeRange IS NOT NULL";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $data['TimeRange']."\t".$data['total']."\r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Was using `date_format` that necessary? In my opinion `hour( column_name ) between 6 and 7` would be a better option.

Comment: @Ravinder - Possibly true, although for the 2nd time range hour on its own wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and if() to use them, this will be along though

Assuming your between (because I don't use that that much) syntax is correct, try this:

```
select count(*) as `total`,
IF(
   DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '06:00:00' and '07:00:00',
   '06:00 - 07:00',
   IF(
      DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '07:30:00' and '08:30:00',
      '07:30 - 08:30',
      IF(
         DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '09:00:00' and '10:00:00',
         '09:00 - 10:00',
         'Other'
      )
   )
) AS `interval`
from `table`
group by `interval`
```

if that doesn't work try:

```
select count(*) as `total`,
IF(
   DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '06:00:00' and '07:00:00',
   '06:00 - 07:00',
   IF(
      DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '07:30:00' and '08:30:00',
      '07:30 - 08:30',
      IF(
         DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '09:00:00' and '10:00:00',
         '09:00 - 10:00',
         'Other'
      )
   )
) AS `interval`
from `table`
group by IF(
   DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '06:00:00' and '07:00:00',
   '06:00 - 07:00',
   IF(
      DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '07:30:00' and '08:30:00',
      '07:30 - 08:30',
      IF(
         DATE_FORMAT(column,'%H:%i:%s') between '09:00:00' and '10:00:00',
         '09:00 - 10:00',
         'Other'
      )
   )
)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: i will sure give it a try and if success vote up for it.thanks for your time.